# Cartesian product of several vectors

Tags: c++, math, vector, combinations, cartesian-product

similar questions have been asked before but I cant find an exact match to my question.

I have 4 vectors each of which hold between 200-500 4 digit integers.  The exact number of elements in each vector varies but I could fix it to a specific value.  I need to find all possible combinations of the elements in these 4 vectors.

eg:

v1[10, 30]
v2[11, 45]
v3[63, 56]
v4[82, 98]

so I'd get something like this:

[10, 11, 63, 82];
[30, 11, 63, 82];
[10, 45, 63, 82];
[10, 45, 56, 82] etc..

Is there a common name for this algorithm so I can find some references to it online?  Otherwise any tips on implementing this in C++ would be helpful.  Performance isn't much of an issue as I only need to run the algorithm once.  Is there anything built into the STL?

Comment: Beware that there will be between 200^4 and 500^4 combinations. 500^4 is 62.5 billion and 200^4 is over 1 billion.

Comment: Wait, if you just had 2 with v1={1,1,2} and v2={1,2}, do you want {1,2} to appear in the output twice? Also, do you consider {1,2} and {2,1} to be the same?

Comment: The common name for this operation is the "Cartesian product".

Comment: Good questions Poita.  There are no duplicate entries within any one vector although there could be duplicate entries across vectors.  I don't consider {1,2} and {2,1} to be the same but removing such occurrences would be advantageous.

Comment: "Would be advantageous"? You really need to specify exactly what you want before you start writing code.

Comment: "Would be advantageous" suggests something that could be beneficial but not entirely critical.

Comment: The astute amongst you may have noticed that the recent change to the question's title has now rendered part of the question obsolete eg "Is there a common name for this algorithm so I can find some references to it online".  In the excitement of the moment the editor must have overlooked this.  Also, where did answer 2 go?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you need this for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279051/how-can-i-create-cartesian-product-of-vector-of-vectors this thread presents some good solutions for the general case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not much of an algorithm...

```
for(vector<int>::const_iterator i1 = v1.begin(); i1 != v1.end(); ++i1)
    for(vector<int>::const_iterator i2 = v2.begin(); i2 != v2.end(); ++i2)
        for(vector<int>::const_iterator i3 = v3.begin(); i3 != v3.end(); ++i3)
            for(vector<int>::const_iterator i4 = v4.begin(); i4 != v4.end(); ++i4)
                cout << "[" << *i1 << "," << *i2 << "," << *i3 << "," << *i4 << "]" << endl;
```

Comment: +1 This is the logical way to do it.  There might be a prettier way to represent but the process would be the same.

Comment: It's times like these you wish you had a meta-for loop that could loop through the for loops.

Comment: +1 Thanks,  this is working of course.  I agree with Poita about the meta loop comment.