# algorithm-agnostic hyperparameter grid search in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, machine-learning, hyperparameters

I would like to compare different machine learning algorithms. As part of that, I need to be able to perform a [grid search for optimal hyperparameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization). However, I am not really into the idea of writing a separate implementation of a grid search for each fixed algorithm and a fixed subset of its hyperparameters. Instead, I would like it to look more like it does in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#exhaustive-grid-search) but perhaps with not as much functionality (I do not need multiple grids, for example) and written in MATLAB.

So far I am trying to understand the logic of the yet to be written `grid_search.m`

```
function model = grid_search(algo, data, labels, varargin)
    p = inputParser;
    % here comes the list of all possible hyperparameters for all algorithms
    % I will just leave three for brevity
    addOptional(p, 'kernel_function', {'linear'});
    addOptional(p, 'rbf_sigma', {1});
    addOptional(p, 'C', {1});

    parse(p, algo, data, labels, varargin{:});

    names = fieldnames(p.Results);
    values = struct2cell(p.Results); % a cell array of cell arrays

    argsize = 2 * length(names);
    args = cell(1, argsize);
    args(1 : 2 : argsize) = names;
    % Now this is the stumbling point.
end
```

The calls to the `grid_search` function should look something like this:

```
m = grid_search('svm', data, labels, 'kernel_function', {'rbf'}, 'C', {[0.1], [1], [10]}, 'rbf_sigma', {[1], [2], [3]})
m = grid_search('knn', data, labels, 'NumNeighbors', {[1], [10]}, 'Distance', {'euclidean', 'cosine'})
```

The first call then would try all the combinations of the rbf kernel with Constraints and Sigmas:

```
{'rbf', 0.1, 1}
{'rbf', 0.1, 2}
{'rbf', 0.1, 3}
{'rbf', 1, 1}
{'rbf', 1, 2}
{'rbf', 1, 3}
{'rbf', 10, 1}
{'rbf', 10, 2}
{'rbf', 10, 3}
```

The idea behind the `args` variable is that it is a cell array of the form `{'name1', 'value1', 'name2', 'value2', ..., 'nameN', 'valueN'}` which would be later on passed to the corresponding algorithm: `algo(data, labels, args{:})`. The `{'name1', 'name2', ..., 'nameN'}` part of it is easy. The problem is that I can't unerstand how to create the `{'value1', 'value2', ..., 'valueN'}` part on each step.

**I understand that machine learning terminology is not known to everybody** Which is why below comes a self-contained example:

Suppose the crew of the TARDIS may consist of the following classes of beings:

```
tardis_crew = {{'doctor'}, {'amy', 'clara'}, {'dalek', 'cyberman', 'master'}}
```

Since there is always just one place for a Timelord, a Companion and a Villain, please show me how to generate the following cell arrays:

```
{'Timelord', 'doctor', 'Companion', 'amy', 'Villain', 'dalek'}
{'Timelord', 'doctor', 'Companion', 'amy', 'Villain', 'cyberman'}
{'Timelord', 'doctor', 'Companion', 'amy', 'Villain', 'master'}
{'Timelord', 'doctor', 'Companion', 'clara', 'Villain', 'dalek'}
{'Timelord', 'doctor', 'Companion', 'clara', 'Villain', 'cyberman'}
{'Timelord', 'doctor', 'Companion', 'clara', 'Villain', 'master'}
```

The solution should be general, i.e. if the number of beings in a class changes or more classes of beings are added, it should still work. I would much appreciate a step-by-step descritption instead of code, too.

PS: The [non-stripped](https://gist.github.com/all3fox/b8e15a637093f17f39e2) github version of the original `grid_search.m` might give you a better idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what you want is to generate the Cartesian product of an arbitrary number of sets. I think this [ALLCOMB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb) function will do that for you, but if you want details of an (iterative) algorithm so you can implement it yourself, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419370/how-can-i-compute-a-cartesian-product-iteratively).

Edit: Thank you by the way for providing a general phrasing for people without ML knowledge.

Comment: I ended up getting a nice trick `[A{:}] = ndgrid(varargin{:})` from the ALLCOMB script and actually rewriting (deleting all the `full()` calls) from the original `ndgrid.m` matlab function. It now works but I have a very vague understanding of it. If I get a better one, I will definitely update. For now, here is the [hackish version](https://gist.github.com/all3fox/615542bdaea8f41e7de1)