# Generating combinations of multiple sets

Tags: c, algorithm, combinations

I am looking for an non-recursive algorithm or C code to generate all combinations of multiple sets (not sure if that's the correct scientific name). For example:

I have N=2 sets of symbols:

```
set 1: [A, Y, Z]
set 2: [1, Q]
```

The output should be:

```
A1
AQ
Y1
YQ
Z1
ZQ
```

N can vary, same as the number of symbols in particular set. Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: You're looking for the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't actually notice that :) But I still have problem with expanding the calculation to accept indefinite number of sets. It's easy for just two, but for N...?

Comment: I'll get back to this in the evening if you haven't received an answer by then.

Comment: Thanks! I will be grateful! :)

Comment: Okay, I managed to do that myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm from: [How can I compute a Cartesian product iteratively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419370/how-can-i-compute-a-cartesian-product-iteratively)

We can make an int array, whose length is n, `int[ ] choose[n]` to keep track of how many elements we have selected among all lists. All elements are set to 0 initially.

Then we iterate through a singly linked list storing all those arrays. If we have iterated an element in array `i`, `choose[i]++`, append it to the result. When choose[i] == array i's length, then break and move on to the next array.

But I don't know how to do the appending since every time we iterate through an array the result's size will be expanded.

If you have figured that out, please let me know.