# In Ruby, how can I iterate over an arbitrary number of arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator

I am doing something very much like the knapsack problem, in which I want to iterate over all combinations of an arbitrary number of inputs.

For example, if my function takes 3 arrays, I want to get all i×j×k combinations. If my function takes 5 arrays, I want to get all i×j×k×l×m combinations.

Example one:

```
result = all_products([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3], [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])

result.length == 120
```

Example two:

```
result = all_products([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3])

result.length == 729
```

But I don't know how many arrays I am going to take in.

What's the way to do this in Ruby?

This is *NOT* asking how to find all pairs of 1 array. My input arrays will likely all be different.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
def self.all_combinations(*sets)
 input = *sets; 
 prod = sets.inject(1) { |p,a| p * a.length } 
 prod.times do |p| 
  args = [] 
  index = p 
  input.each do |array| 
    quotient = index / array.length
    remainder = index % array.length
    args << array[remainder] 
    index = quotient
    pp args 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Not a dupe. Please read the question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give a small sample array and expected output?

Comment: Pass the args in with a splat operator for arbitrary number of args `all_products(*products)` This will assign them to `products` as an array of arrays. After that you should figure out how to cartesian product them.

Comment: @MichaelPapile, I know about splat. The question is how to iterate over the N arrays I will have at that point, not knowing how many arrays there will be when I write the function.

Comment: Well, here's my attempt, using "pp" as my sample function. If you can't read it, ask the guy who locked this post.   def self.all_combinations(*sets)
    input = *sets;
    prod = sets.inject(1) { |p,a| p * a.length } 
    prod.times { |p|
      args = []
      index = p
      input.each { |array|
        quotient = index  / array.length
        remainder = index % array.length
        args << array[remainder]
        index = quotient
      }
      pp args
    }
  end

Comment: This is a Cartesian product of arrays/sets. Once you have that splat put the arrays into an array it does not matter how many are entered. There are a ton of answers of this such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419370/how-can-i-compute-a-cartesian-product-iteratively  Not in Ruby but it the logic is the same. You can do it iteratively or tail recursively.

Answer (score 1):

I would start off with getting the 'product' of 2 arrays:

```
def product2(array1, array2)
  array1.map { |e1| array2.map { |e2| e1*e2 } }.flatten
end
```

You can then generalize to any number of arrays:

```
def all_products(*arrays)
  arrays.reduce([1]) { |result, array| product2(result, array) }
end
```

You might want to handle corner cases (for example empty arrays or no input arrays at all)