# get all combinations between set elements

Tags: c++, combinations

given a vector > SETS such that

```
SETS[0] = {1,2,3}
SETS[1] = {11,22,33}
SETS[2] = {111,222,333}
```

I want to create all the vectors

```
{1,11,111} ... {1,11,333}, {1,22,111} ... {1,22,333} ... {3,11,111} ... {3,33,333}
```

I've looked for it in boost doc but didn't find anything.
Before than writing the code on my own, is there any library containing a function solving this problem?

Comment: 1) I doubt any library would provide this functionality. 2) It shouldn't be difficult to write code to do this. 3) I saw an almost identical question on StackOverflow not too long ago (but I'm not going to go looking for it). And I'm sure there are many other near-identical questions.

Comment: `next_permutation` much?

Comment: i think next_permutation solves this problem only if the three sets have the same number of elements... i'd like a more general algorithm

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: This isn't a permutation, it's a cartesian product.

Comment: Roll your own. Simple recursion will do it nicely.

Comment: @interjay hmm, then recursive `for` loop will do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create cartesian product of vector of vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279051/how-can-i-create-cartesian-product-of-vector-of-vectors)

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279051/how-can-i-create-cartesian-product-of-vector-of-vectors