# How can I map one set of values to another?

Tags: algorithm

---

## EDIT

Just found another thread on SO that's pretty much exactly what I needed: [How can I create cartesian product of vector of vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279051/how-can-i-create-cartesian-product-of-vector-of-vectors)

Thanks everyone!

---

Let's say I have one set of values `S1(A, B, C)` and another, `S2(D, E, F)`, where a transformation `S1 -> S2` will give another set, `S3`, where `S3(AD, AE, AF, BD, BE, BF, CD, CE, CF)`; in other words, I'd like to map each value of the first set to each value of the second set, thus getting a third set that has a size of `S1 x S1`.

Now, doing this for two sets is a trivial matter, however, I am at a loss when it comes to have a variable number of sets, i.e. `S1 -> S2 -> S3 -> ... -> Sn`

If we view this as a tree/graph structure, the problem is solved by finding every single path:

```
        start
          .
    .     .     .
   A      B      C
   .      .      .
 . . .  . . .  . . .
 D E F  D E F  D E F
```

Is there a scalable algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: Check out [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). I know some languages have this built-in. For example, Python has `itertools.product(*iterables)`

Comment: @Kevin actually stumbled upon it [just 2 minutes ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28set_theory%29); unfortunately, i don't think C++ has this.

Comment: Google n-ary cartesian product. There're many variations, but all have O(n^2) complexity.

Answer (score 2):

This, by definition, would be recursion.  If you put all of these sets into a multi-dimensional array you could easily recurse through all of the different levels and create your final set.

Comment: What Kirkland means is that, in general, tree-like structures can be traversed with a recursive algorithm, where you treat each node of the tree (except for the leaf ones) as its own tree. Of course, without a code example, that's pretty hard to visualize.