# Find a combination of elements from different arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sum, combinations

I recently started learning C++ and ran into problems with this task:
I am given 4 arrays of different lengths with different values.

```
   vector<int> A = {1,2,3,4};
    vector<int> B = {1,3,44};
    vector<int> C = {1,23};
    vector<int> D = {0,2,5,4};
```

I need to implement a function that goes through all possible variations of the elements of these vectors and checks if there are such values a from array A, b from array B, c from array C and d from array D that their sum would be 0(a+b+c+d=0)
I wrote such a program, but it outputs 1, although the desired combination does not exist.

```
using namespace std;

    vector<int> test;
    int sum (vector<int> v){
        int sum_of_elements = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            sum_of_elements += v[i];
        }
        return sum_of_elements;
    }
    
    bool abcd0(vector<int> A,vector<int> B,vector<int> C,vector<int> D){
        for ( int ai = 0; ai <= A.size(); ai++){
            test[0] = A[ai];
            for ( int bi = 0; bi <= B.size(); bi++){
                test[1] = B[bi];
                for ( int ci = 0; ci <= C.size(); ci++){
                    test[2] = C[ci];
                    for ( int di = 0; di <= D.size(); di++){
                        test[3] = D[di];
                        if (sum (test) == 0){
                            return true;
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would be happy if you could explain what the problem is

Comment: The first step is to generate the [cartesian product of your vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279051/how-can-i-create-cartesian-product-of-vector-of-vectors). Then for each set of values, you can check your sum.

Comment: `test` is empty so `test[0]` etc. has undefined behaviour. As `test` is empty `sum` will always return `0`

Comment: `ai <= A.size()` => `ai < A.size()`, likewise for all the rest.

Comment: @AlanBirtles But I add elements from these 4 vectors to the test in the function. or it is stored only inside the function abcd0, and outside the function the test remains empty?

Comment: @Theresa *and ran into problems with this task* -- Is this task one from a "competitive coding" website, or one given to you by your teacher?  If it is from a website, let me warn you that your intended solution may get "time out" errors if you were to submit the solution, especially if the arrays have a large number of elements.

Comment: nothing in the code you've posted adds elements to `test`, please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles, ah, ok, thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Vectors don't increase their size by themself. You either need to construct with right size, [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) it, or [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) elements (you can also [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), but vectors arent very efficient at that). In your code you never add any element to `test` and accessing any element, eg `test[0] = A[ai];` causes undefined behavior.

Further, valid indices are `[0, size())` (ie `size()` excluded, it is not a valid index). Hence your loops are accessing the input vectors out-of-bounds, causing undefined behavior again. The loops conditions should be `for ( int ai = 0; ai < A.size(); ai++){`.

Not returning something from a non-`void` function is again undefined behavior. When your `abcd0` does not find a combination that adds up to `0` it does not return anything.

After fixing those issues your code does produce the expected output: https://godbolt.org/z/KvW1nePMh.

However, I suggest you to...

- not use global variables. It makes the code difficult to reason about. For example we need to see all your code to know if you actually do resize `test`. If `test` was local to `abcd0` we would only need to consider that function to know what happens to `test`.
- read about [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- not pass parameters by value when you can pass them by `const` reference to avoid unnecessary copies.
- using range based for loops helps to avoid making mistakes with the bounds.

Trying to change not more than necessary, your code could look like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int sum (const std::vector<int>& v){
    int sum_of_elements = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        sum_of_elements += v[i];
    }
    return sum_of_elements;
}
    
bool abcd0(const std::vector<int>& A,
            const std::vector<int>& B,
            const std::vector<int>& C,
            const std::vector<int>& D){

    for (const auto& a : A){
        for (const auto& b : B){
            for (const auto& c : C){
                for (const auto& d : D){
                    if (sum ({a,b,c,d}) == 0){
                        return true;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A = {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> B = {1,3,44};
    std::vector<int> C = {1,23};
    std::vector<int> D = {0,2,5,4};
    std::cout << abcd0(A,B,C,D);
}
```

Note that I removed the vector `test` completely. You don't need to construct it explicitly, but you can pass a temporary to `sum`. `sum` could use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), or you could simply add the four numbers directly in `abcd0`. I suppose this is for exercise, so let's leave it at that.

Comment: Why is there a need to declare `test` vector when it is not being used anywhere?

Comment: @Beginner there is none. I first wanted to keep it to stay as close as possible to OPs code, though then I was too lazy to assign to its elements, but forgot to remove it

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** : The answer written by @463035818_is_not_a_number is the answer you should refer to.

---

As mentioned in the comments by @Alan Birtles, there's nothing in that code that adds elements to `test`. Also, as mentioned in comments by @PaulMcKenzie, the condition in loops should be modified. Currently, it is looping all the way up to the size of the vector which is invalid(since the index runs from 0 to the size of vector-1). For implementing the algorithm that you've in mind (as I inferred from your code), you can declare and initialise the vector all the way down in the 4th loop.
Here's the modified code,

```
int sum (vector<int> v){
    int sum_of_elements = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        sum_of_elements += v[i];
    }
    return sum_of_elements;
}

bool abcd0(vector<int> A,vector<int> B,vector<int> C,vector<int> D){

    for ( int ai = 0; ai <A.size(); ai++){
        for ( int bi = 0; bi <B.size(); bi++){
            for ( int ci = 0; ci <C.size(); ci++){
                for ( int di = 0; di <D.size(); di++){
                    vector<int> test = {A[ai], B[bi], C[ci], D[di]};
                    if (sum (test) == 0){
                        return true;
                    }
                } 
            }
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

The algorithm is inefficient though. You can try sorting the vectors first. Loop  through the first two of them while using the 2 pointer technique to check if desired sum is available from the remaining two vectors

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me, like you're calling the function every time you want to check an array. Within the function you're initiating `int sum_of_elements = 0;`.

So at the first run, you're starting with `int sum_of_elements = 0;`.
It finds the element and increases `sum_of_elements` up to 1.

Second run you're calling the function and it initiates again with `int sum_of_elements = 0;`.
This is repeated every time you're checking the next array for the element.

Let me know if I understood that correctly (didn't run it, just skimmed a bit).

Comment: the `sum` function simply counts the sum of elements of the array.
In the function abcd0 I add the first possible combination to the test array, and then I check if the sum of the elements is 0. If it is, fine, output is 1, if not the combination must be changed