# Creating a function showing all combinations

Tags: c++, for-loop, matrix, combinations, cartesian-product

I'm having trouble here turning a vector of vectors with different lengths into a matrix with all possible combinations. For example, I am wanting the below

```
vector <vector <double>> matrix1{{10, 20, 30}, {1}, {2, 3}, {1}};
```

to turn into

```
{10, 1, 2, 1}
{10, 1, 3, 1}
{20, 1, 2, 1}
{20, 1, 3, 1}
{30, 1, 2, 1}
{30, 1, 3, 1}
```

I've come up with the below, which gives me some of the above, but I am obviously missing the ones where c = 3 and a = 20, c = 3 and a = 30.

```
vector <vector <double>> TransformMatrix(vector<vector<double>> matrix)
{
    vector <vector <double>> fullmatrix;
    for (int a = 0; a < matrix[0].size(); a++)
    {
        vector <double> v1;
        v1.push_back(matrix[0][a]);
        v1.push_back(matrix[1][0]);
        v1.push_back(matrix[2][0]);
        v1.push_back(matrix[3][0]);
        fullmatrix.push_back(v1);
    }
    for (int b = 1; b < matrix[1].size(); b++)
    {
        vector <double> v1;
        v1.push_back(matrix[0][0]);
        v1.push_back(matrix[1][b]);
        v1.push_back(matrix[2][0]);
        v1.push_back(matrix[3][0]);
        fullmatrix.push_back(v1);
    
    }
....
}
```

Does anyone have any helpful hints / tips here?

Comment: Before handing out this kind of a class assignment or homework I would expect the C++ instructor or teacher to explain the fundamental algorithm that needs to be executed here. Which part of your instructor's explanation, specifically, was unclear? Is this how your teacher explain this should be done? Was there any mention of recursion?

Comment: In C++23 (you need a very new compiler) there is this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/cartesian_product_view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is obtain the inputs to an n-dimensional Cartesian product.
The conventional solution is to write an iterative and recursive function:

```cpp
void cartesian_n_pick(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> &in,
                      std::vector<std::vector<double>> &out,
                      std::vector<double> &stack,
                      std::size_t i = 0)
{
    // base case: there is nothing more to loop over, so we do something
    //            with the current stack
    if (i >= in.size()) {
        out.push_back(stack);
        return;
    }
    // regular case: we loop over in[i] and recurse, which translates into an
    //               n-dimensional for-loop
    for (double x : in[i]) {
        stack.push_back(x);
        cartesian_n_pick(in, out, stack, i + 1);
        stack.pop_back();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix = /* ... */;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> combinations;
    std::vector<double> stack;
    cartesian_n_pick(in, combinations, stack);
}
```

Also note that it's excessive and probably unnecessary to store all results in `out`. You might be able to just process the `stack` whenever needed instead of storing all possible stacks in a vector first.

See also [How can I create cartesian product of vector of vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5279051/5740428) for similar solutions.