# Fetch combination of tokens from a 2D Vector of strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, token

I have a 2D vector `vecTokens` which has sub vectors of string tokens. I need to have a resultant vector of string with size = result of multiplication of sizes of all sub vector in `vecTokens` where each element has to be a combination of string tokens separated by "|" as shown in vector `finalResults`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<string>> vecTokens
    {
        {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, // 4 tokens
        {"101", "102", "103"}, // 3 tokens
    };
    
    //Size is 4*3 = 12
    vector<string> finalResults
    {
        "1|101", "1|102", "1|103",
        "2|101", "2|102", "2|103",
        "3|101", "3|102", "3|103",
        "4|101", "4|102", "4|103"
    };
    return 0;
}
```

If the `vecTokens` is modified to include more elements like

```
vector<vector<string>> tokens
{
    {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, // 4 tokens
    {"101", "102", "103"}, // 3 tokens
    {"6", "7"}, // 2 tokens
};
```

the `finalResults` should look like

```
//Size is 4*3*2 = 24
vector<string> finalResults
{
    "1|101|6", "1|101|7", "1|102|6", "1|102|7", "1|103|6", "1|103|7",
    "2|101|6", "2|101|7", "2|102|6", "2|102|7", "2|103|6", "2|103|7",
    "3|101|6", "3|101|7", "3|102|6", "3|102|7", "3|103|6", "3|103|7",
    "4|101|6", "4|101|7", "4|102|6", "4|102|7", "4|103|6", "4|103|7",
};
```

Currently I am stuck on what approach should be followed for achieving the results. Any standard algorithms which do something similar would also be helpful.

Comment: So, you basically want to calculate a cartesian product of your vectors. It's not really a fresh problem. E.g. [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279051/how-can-i-create-cartesian-product-of-vector-of-vectors).

Answer (score 0):

The main observation is regarding the size of the resultant vector, and the index of elements combining each element.

Lets denote your vectors by `v_1, ..., v_k`, with their sizes `n_1, ... n_k` respectively.

The size is the multiplication `n_1 * ... * n_k`, and for each `0 <= i < size`, the element `i` is combined from the elements `(i%(n_2 * ... * n_k), i%(n_3 * ... * n_k),..., i%1`.

In your second example, you can see that other words, the identity of the first element changes every `6` consecutive elements, the second every `2` consecutive elements, and the third every `1`.

Thus, to achieve this, you can simply write something like

```
int size; // n_1 * ... * n_k
vector<int> sizes; // (n_1, ..., n_k)
vector<string> res(size);
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i ++) {
  vector<int> index_tuple = compute_index_tuple(i, sizes);
  res[i] = concatenate_with_bars(vecTokens, index_tuple);
}
```

where `compute_index_tuple` does all of the modulos described above, and `concatenate_with_bars` takes the `index_tuple[k]` element from `vecTokens[k]` and concatenates it with `|` character.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a directed graph from those values and run a DFS (for all nodes in first row) to get cartesian product strings you desire.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>

struct GraphNode
{
    std::string val;
    std::vector<int> neighbor_indices;   // Directed edges
};

class Graph
{
    std::vector<GraphNode> nodes;
    std::map<std::string, int> node_index;
    std::vector<int> start_set; // set of ids for which dfs must be run

    void dfs(int start_i, std::vector<std::string>& v)
    {
        using P = std::pair<int, std::string>;

        std::stringstream ss;
        std::stack<P> s;
        s.push({start_i, ""});
        while (!s.empty())
        {
            auto [i, str] = s.top();
            s.pop();

            const auto& node = nodes[i];
            str += node.val;

            if (node.neighbor_indices.empty())
            {
                v.push_back(str);
                continue;
            }

            str += '|';

            for (int n : node.neighbor_indices)
            {
                s.push({n, str});
            }
        }
    }
public:
    Graph(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& v)
    {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            const auto& v1 = v[i - 1];
            const auto& v2 = v[i];
            
            // construct nodes if not present
            for (const auto& val : v1)
            {
                if (node_index.find(val) == node_index.end())
                {
                    GraphNode new_node{val};
                    nodes.push_back(new_node);
                    node_index[val] = nodes.size() - 1;
                }
            }

            // construct nodes if not present
            for (const auto& val : v2)
            {
                if (node_index.find(val) == node_index.end())
                {
                    GraphNode new_node{val};
                    nodes.push_back(new_node);
                    node_index[val] = nodes.size() - 1;
                }
            }

            // add directed edge from v1 nodes to v2 nodes
            for (const auto& val1 : v1)
            {
                int val1_index = node_index[val1];
                for (const auto& val2 : v2)
                {
                    int val2_index = node_index[val2];

                    nodes[val1_index].neighbor_indices.push_back(val2_index);
                }
            }
        }

        for (const auto& val : v[0])
        {
            start_set.push_back(node_index[val]);
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (const auto& graphNode : nodes)
        {
            std::cout << graphNode.val << ": ";
            for (int i : graphNode.neighbor_indices)
            {
                std::cout << nodes[i].val << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::string> get_cartesian_product()
    {
        std::vector<std::string> result;
        
        for (int i : start_set)
        {
            dfs(i, result);
        }

        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vecTokens
    {
        {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, // 4 tokens
        {"101", "102", "103"}, // 3 tokens
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vecTokens2
    {
        {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, // 4 tokens
        {"101", "102", "103"}, // 3 tokens
        {"6", "7"}, // 2 tokens
    };

    Graph one{vecTokens};
    //one.print();
    for (const auto& s : one.get_cartesian_product())
    {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "---------------------------------\n";
    Graph two{vecTokens2};
    //two.print();
    for (const auto& s : two.get_cartesian_product())
    {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```